Ubuntu 22.04 / Kubernetes & DNSMasq
I have DNSMasq and Kubernetes running on a series of Ubuntu 22.04 virtual machines.
After installing any CNI (in this case, Cilium), when CoreDNS attempts to startup, I get a crash loop with the following error:
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration SHA512 = 591cf328cccc12bc490481273e738df59329c62c0b729d94e8b61db9961c2fa5f046dd37f1cf888b953814040d180f52594972691cd6ff41be96639138a43908
CoreDNS-1.11.1
linux/amd64, go1.20.7, ae2bbc2
[FATAL] plugin/loop: Loop (127.0.0.1:34497 -> :53) detected for zone ".", see https://coredns.io/plugins/loop#troubleshooting. Query: "HINFO 3269900349428274078.2103260678397829079."

I'm aware of the "hack" to modify the coredns configmap, and remove the loop line, however I wanted to see if there was any other ways around it?
Some diagnoses commands and their outputs:
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 53
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8277/dnsmasq        
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      8277/dnsmasq        
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53              0.0.0.0:*                           8277/dnsmasq        
udp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                                8277/dnsmasq  

DNSMasq Status
systemctl status dnsmasq
● dnsmasq.service - dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-06-05 21:33:02 UTC; 4s ago
    Process: 8261 ExecStartPre=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq checkconfig (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 8269 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-exec (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 8278 ExecStartPost=/etc/init.d/dnsmasq systemd-start-resolvconf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 8277 (dnsmasq)
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9241)
     Memory: 576.0K
        CPU: 27ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/dnsmasq.service
             └─8277 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq -x /run/dnsmasq/dnsmasq.pid -u dnsmasq -7 /etc/dnsmasq.d,.dpkg-dist,.dpkg-old,.dpkg-new --local-service --trust-anchor=.,20326,8,2,e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc6834571>

Jun 05 21:33:02 ucstg-worker-2 dnsmasq[8277]: using nameserver 8.8.4.4#53
Jun 05 21:33:02 ucstg-worker-2 dnsmasq[8277]: using nameserver 10.96.0.10#53 for domain cluster.local
Jun 05 21:33:02 ucstg-worker-2 dnsmasq[8277]: reading /etc/resolv.conf
Jun 05 21:33:02 ucstg-worker-2 dnsmasq[8277]: using nameserver 8.8.8.8#53
Jun 05 21:33:02 ucstg-worker-2 dnsmasq[8277]: using nameserver 1.1.1.1#53
Jun 05 21:33:02 ucstg-worker-2 dnsmasq[8277]: using nameserver 8.8.4.4#53
Jun 05 21:33:02 ucstg-worker-2 dnsmasq[8277]: using nameserver 10.96.0.10#53 for domain cluster.local

/etc/resolv.conf
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1

dnsmasq.conf
cat /etc/dnsmasq.conf
port=53
server=8.8.8.8
server=1.1.1.1
server=8.8.4.4
server=/cluster.local/10.96.0.10
listen-address=::1,127.0.0.1
except-interface=lo

Systemd-resolv status
sudo systemctl status systemd-resolved
○ systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network-configuration-managers
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver-clients

Jun 05 20:38:00 ucstg-worker-2 systemd[1]: Starting Network Name Resolution...
Jun 05 20:38:00 ucstg-worker-2 systemd-resolved[661]: Positive Trust Anchors:
Jun 05 20:38:00 ucstg-worker-2 systemd-resolved[661]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b8f1d39a95c0b0d7c65d08458e880409bbc683457104237c7f8ec8d
Jun 05 20:38:00 ucstg-worker-2 systemd-resolved[661]: Negative trust anchors: home.arpa 10.in-addr.arpa 16.172.in-addr.arpa 17.172.in-addr.arpa 18.172.in-addr.arpa 19.172.in-addr.arpa 20.172.in-addr.arpa 21.172.in-addr.a>
Jun 05 20:38:00 ucstg-worker-2 systemd-resolved[661]: Using system hostname 'ucstg-worker-2'.
Jun 05 20:38:00 ucstg-worker-2 systemd[1]: Started Network Name Resolution.
Jun 05 20:38:45 ucstg-worker-2 systemd-resolved[661]: Clock change detected. Flushing caches.
Jun 05 20:57:22 ucstg-worker-2 systemd[1]: Stopping Network Name Resolution...
Jun 05 20:57:22 ucstg-worker-2 systemd[1]: systemd-resolved.service: Deactivated successfully.
Jun 05 20:57:22 ucstg-worker-2 systemd[1]: Stopped Network Name Resolution.

And lastly, a simple dig, to show something is working :)
dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.18-0ubuntu0.22.04.2-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 6972
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.                    IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.             28      IN      A       172.217.16.206

;; Query time: 8 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Jun 05 21:41:23 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55

If there's anything else needed, please ask!
